# umount bind of stale NFS

Tags: linux, nfs, mount

i've got a problem removing mounts created with `mount -o bind` from a locally mounted NFS folder. Assume the following mount structure:

NFS mounted directory:

```
$ mount -o rw,soft,tcp,intr,timeo=10,retrans=2,retry=1 \
 10.20.0.1:/srv/source /srv/nfs-source
```

Bound directory:

```
$ mount -o bind /srv/nfs-source/sub1 /srv/bind-target/sub1
```

Which results in this mount map

```
$ mount
/dev/sda1 on / type ext3 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
# ...
10.20.0.1:/srv/source on /srv/nfs-source type nfs (rw,soft,tcp,intr,timeo=10,retrans=2,retry=1,addr=10.20.0.100)
/srv/nfs-source/sub1 on /srv/bind-target/sub1 type none (rw,bind)
```

If the server (`10.20.0.1`) goes down (eg `ifdown eth0`), the handles become stale, which is expected.

I can now un-mount the NFS mount with force

```
$ umount -f /srv/nfs-source
```

This takes some seconds, but works without any problems. However, i cannot un-mount the bound directory in `/srv/bind-target/sub1`. The forced `umount` results in:

```
$ umount -f /srv/bind-target/sub1
umount2: Stale NFS file handle
umount: /srv/bind-target/sub1: Stale NFS file handle
umount2: Stale NFS file handle
```

Here is a trace http://pastebin.com/ipvvrVmB

I've tried umounting the sub-directories beforehand, find any processes accessing anything within the NFS or bind mounts (there are none).

`lsof` also complains:

```
$ lsof -n
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() nfs file system /srv/nfs-source
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() nfs file system /srv/bind-target/sub1 (deleted)
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() nfs file system /srv/bind-target/
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

I've tried with recent stable Linux kernels 3.2.17, 3.2.19 and 3.3.8 (cannot use 3.4.x, cause need the grsecurity patch, which is not, yet, supported - grsecurity is not patched in in the tests above!).

My nfs-utils are version 1.2.2 (debian stable).

Does anybody have an idea how i can either:

- force the un-mount some other way? (any dirty trick is welcome, data loss or damage neglible at this point)
- use something else instead of `mount -o bind`? (cannot use soft links, cause mounted directories will be used in chroot; `bindfs` via FUSE is far to slow to be an option)

Thanks,
Paul

**Update 1**

- With 2.6.32.59 the umount of the (stale) sub-mounts work just fine. It seems to be a kernel regression bug.
- The above tests where with NFSv3. Additional tests with NFSv4 showed no change.

**Update 2**

- We have tested now multiple 2.6 and 3.x kernels and are now sure, that this was introduced in 3.0.x. We will fille a bug report, hopefully they figure it out.

Comment: Try `umount -l`

Comment: @Dimitri: Sorry, did not mention this. I've tried, does not work. Neither does `umount -lf`.

Comment: What happens if you unmount the `/srv/bind-target/sub1` first and then is `/srv/nfs-source`?

Comment: @quanta: Same thing. Also the trace looks exactly the same.

Comment: Is the question on how to handle the current situation without rebooting, or on how to make the system resilient to that problem in the future?

Comment: @rackandboneman: The former would be the question: How can the stale and unusable mount points be removed without reboot. Resilience is achieved via data redundancy and node failover (in a dynamic infrastructure, where one cannot guarantee static/predict IP addresses), but it cannot be implemented as long as the stale directories exist.

Answer (score 2):

Something that worked for me in my particular setup, to get cleints working, was this:

I had an autofs tree with a mounted nfs fs on /fs/doom and another mounted on /fs/doom/localvol5. After server reboot it was possible to access /fs/doom and /fs/doom/localvol5/sub, but /fs/doom/localvol5 itself gave ESTALE on everything, including umount -f, -l, -fl.

What I did to get the client running without reboot was to move the whole /fs/doom hierarchy to another tree:

```
    mkdir /dev/shm/garbage-mount
    mount --move /fs/doom /dev/shm/garbage-mount
```

That moved the whole tree, and apparently works only because /fs/doom was accessible and a mountpoint. I sitll cannot unmount any of these filesystems, but I was able to restart autofs and get a fresh and working tree.

This should work with any autofs tree that has malfunctioning nfs subdirs.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply mount the remote filesystem on /srv/bind-target/sub1.

If you're expecting this level of unavailability you should also specify the sync (although maybe defailt) option to NFS to lower the chance of having unwritten changes on your client

Answer (score 1):

```
$ umount -l
```

Worked for me, before none of them were working:

```
$ mount -f ...
```

Comment: Posting blind commands is generally a poor way to answer questions - it encourages [voodoo system administration](http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/06/09/press-the-green-button-twice/). Please update your post to clarify what the commands do and *why* they're useful so the OP can actually learn something...

Comment: He also mention [over a year ago](http://serverfault.com/questions/396208/umount-bind-of-stale-nfs#comment412277_396208) that he's tried this.